# ListView - динамическое заполнение в javа

Tags: android, listview, textview

Столкнулся со сложной практикой в разработке простейшей игры-симулятора. В игре 4 экрана с разными списками действий. Для переходов между ними использую `ViewFlipper`, для списка - `ListView`. В игре есть 7 показателей (деньги, опыт и т.д) Каждое действие в игре зависит от этих показателей и влечет за собой их увеличение/уменьшение. Причем, разные действия приносят разные эффекты (например, "пойти на работу" приносит эффект уменьшения бодрости, но увеличения денег, тогда как "купить еду" - уменьшения денег, но увеличения сытости и т.п). Каждое действие осуществляется нажатием на определенный айтем (элемент `ListView`). В каждом айтеме есть текст действия и его эффекты. Так как, все эффекты разные, а делать для каждого свою разметку нелогично, придется заполнять его статичными данными. Но причем, само заполнение будет зависить от других данных, тоесть будет динамичным. Разберем на примере одного `ListView`:

**item.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/item_selector"
android:gravity="left">

<TextView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:text="GO"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:id="@+id/name_item"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:weightSum="7">

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="+15"
        android:textColor="#F95D1C"
        android:textSize="19sp"
        android:id="@+id/vdohnovenie"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="+15"
        android:textColor="#FFA000"
        android:textSize="19sp"
        android:id="@+id/popular"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="+15"
        android:textColor="#F0FF00"
        android:textSize="19sp"
        android:id="@+id/money"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="+15"
        android:textColor="#00FF00"
        android:textSize="19sp"
        android:id="@+id/guitar"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="+15"
        android:textColor="#00AAFF"
        android:textSize="19sp"
        android:id="@+id/vokal"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="+15"
        android:textColor="#5F7FD0"
        android:textSize="19sp"
        android:id="@+id/harizma"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="+15"
        android:textColor="#AE51C7"
        android:textSize="19sp"
        android:id="@+id/style"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Кусок кода из java**

```
String[] summary_lv2 = {"Слушать радио", "Выпить пива", "Общаться с крутыми музыкантами", "Выпить пива с музыкантами", "Слушать комп", "Слушать винил",  "Концерт местной группы", "Концерт отечественной группы", "Концерт зарубежной группы"};

String[] secondary_vdxnvn_lv2 = {"5", "15", "10", "15", "10", "15", "30", "50", "80"};
String[] secondary_popular_lv2 = {"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""};
String[] secondary_money_lv2 = {"", "-60", "", "-120", "", "", "-400", "-600", "-1000"};
String[] secondary_guitar_lv2 = {"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""};
String[] secondary_vokal_lv2 = {"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""};
String[] secondary_harizma_lv2 = {"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "1", "1"};
String[] secondary_style_lv2 = {"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "1"};
String[] from = {"name_item", "vdoxnovenie", "popular", "money", "guitar", "vokal", "harizma", "style"};
int[] to = {R.id.name_item, R.id.vdohnovenie, R.id.popular, R.id.money, R.id.guitar, R.id.vokal, R.id.harizma, R.id.style};
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrayList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
HashMap<String, String> hashmap;
for(int i = 0; i < summary_lv2.length; i++){
hashmap = new HashMap<String, String>();
hashmap.put("name_item", "" + summary_lv2[i]);
hashmap.put("vdoxnovenie", "+" + secondary_vdxnvn_lv2[i]);
hashmap.put("popular", "" + secondary_popular_lv2[i]);
hashmap.put("money", "" + secondary_money_lv2[i]);
hashmap.put("guitar", "" + secondary_guitar_lv2[i]);
hashmap.put("vokal", "" + secondary_vokal_lv2[i]);
hashmap.put("harizma", "" + secondary_harizma_lv2[i]);
hashmap.put("style", "" + secondary_style_lv2[i]);
arrayList.add(hashmap);
}
SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, arrayList, R.layout.item, from, to);
lv1.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Например, когда эффекта, связанного с деньгами, нет - я передаю пустые кавычки и тем самым эффект не показывается. Таким образом, в эффектах будет располагаться только полезная информация (вдохновение +0 и т.п. не будет, такие данные показывать нет смысла).

А теперь **вопросы**:

1) Игрок должен понять, что делает тот или иной эффект, какой показатель он меняет, поэтому в TextView через атрибут `drawableRight` необходимо добавить значок (монетка, вдохновение и т.п) Но ведь, когда эффект показывать не нужно, в `TextView` мало будет передать пустые кавычки, так как значок останется на своем месте. Как заставить его тоже не показываться в случае, если текст пуст?

2) В случае, если в `TextView` передаются пустые кавычки, `view`-элемент не показывается и его "место" тоже. В итоге, те `TextView`, в которые передаются значения, отличные от `null`, показываются друг за другом, по горизонтали, будто тех `TextView`, в которые ничего не передается вообще нет. Отлично, мне это как раз и надо. Но, дело в том, что они прижаты друг к другу. А если им всем присвоить атрибут типа `layout_marginRight`? Конечно, отступы появляются, они разделены, но в случае передачи пустых кавычек, `TextView` текст, конечно, не отображает, но место занимает. В итоге, на их месте встают пробелы, что смотрится очень некрасиво. Так вот, как сделать, чтобы и отступы были и места от "пустых" `TextView` не было. Просьба, не предлагать что-то типа "передавай в `TextView` цифру и пробелы. Мне потом нужно сделать слушатель, который эти цифры будет брать. А лишний раз, замедлять работу игры вырезкой цифр от пробелов - нехорошо. Жду хороших советов от опытных разработчиков. Мучаюсь уже неделю. Заранее спасибо :)

Каким образом можно решить проблему с адаптером? Дайте ссылку, куда копать

Comment: я в геймдев не влезаю, но на первый вопрос возможно отвечу: попробуйте сделать обычную проверку на кавычки
if(s.equals("")){
view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}else{
.....
}

Comment: @Asgard, и куда же его писать? Все данные уходят через `SimpleCursorAdapter` в view-элементы. Для этой проверки передаваемое значение надо ловить в кастомном адаптере, **который я делать не хочу**. Я стремлюсь к минимуму кода. Было б так просто, я бы вопрос не задавал :))))

Comment: хотите и шоколадку съесть, и на ёлочку сесть)

Comment: @Asgard, вы правы. Нужен адаптер

Comment: Стремясь к минимуму кода таким способом вы создаете такие костыли, что я не позавидую тому, кто потом этот код будет поддерживать. Стремится к минимуму нужно не в ущерб простоты и работоспособности кода.

Comment: @temq, хорошо :)